# Magento 2: How to get custom product attribute value programatically

Tags: magento2

I have created custom Product Attribute group as follow. how can i access attribute values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the product attribute values from the product object like,

```
$product->getData('label'); or $product->getLabel();
```

You have to pass your custom attribute code in the above code.

In phtml file you can use the `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` block to get the product object. Check the below example.

```
<?php
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php 
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    echo $_product ->getData('label');
?>
```

Comment: which block should i use for $product

Comment: I have updated my answer.